# Why using ClassVar's attributes in a dataclass has no effect?

Tags: python, class, oop

Considering this example :

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclass
class Circle:
    radius: float
    pi: ClassVar[float] = 3.14159


circle1 = Circle(5.0)
circle2 = Circle(10.0)

circle1.pi = 3.14
```

---

```
print(circle1) # gives Circle(radius=5.0)
print(circle1.pi) # gives 3.14
```

I'm very confused because I can't see the difference between using `pi: ClassVar[float] = 3.14159` and `pi: float = 3.14159`.

Sorry but can someone explain why and where `ClassVar` can be useful ?

Comment: Note that `Circle.pi` is defined, but `Circle.radius` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables)

> it is excluded from consideration as a field and is ignored by the dataclass mechanism

That means that you won't see it in the string representation of a a dataclass instances

Also modifying it as `Class.attribute` will result in modification for every object of the class (if you try `Circle.radius = 3.14` is has no effect)

```
circle1 = Circle(5.0)
circle2 = Circle(10.0)
print(circle1.radius, circle1.pi) # 5.0  3.14159
print(circle2.radius, circle2.pi) # 10.0 3.14159


Circle.pi = 3.14

print(circle1.radius, circle1.pi) # 5.0  3.14
print(circle2.radius, circle2.pi) # 10.0 3.14
```

Comment: Your last sentence has stirred up the confusion I had, thanks @azro.